# Is it possible to prevent some icons/applications from jumping of the Dock?

Tags: dock, icon, desktop

some applications are annoying and sometimes "jump" event it isn't really necessary. Example:

[image: jumping icon]

Would it be possible to prevent this?

Comment: While the example you show is higher than I have ever seen it is standard for an icon to jump when you click on it to launch or to jump when it wants your attention. But in System Settings there is an option to Animate the icon at launch, which you can turn off.