# How can I copy the text of a link on Google Chrome for iOS?

Tags: ios, google-chrome, copy-paste

How can I copy the text of a link on Google Chrome for iOS?

Example from [Is it possible to prevent some icons/applications from jumping of the Dock?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/463805/20338):

[image]

I’d like to copy the question title:

> Is it possible to prevent some icons/applications from jumping of the Dock?

When I long click on the link, the only options I see are:

[image]

I use an iPhone mini 12 with iOS 15.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://redd.it/167dc55 mentions two options:

> 1. Take a screenshot and copy it from there. (Author: Reddit user [throwawaybutofcourse](https://www.reddit.com/user/throwawaybutofcourse))
> 2. Hold somewhere that’s not the headline link, like right next to it, then move the copy and paste to the headline. (Author: Reddit user [rootshirt](https://www.reddit.com/user/rootshirt))